# How do I add a database to an android app in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've never developed an android app before. I'm using Android Studio. The app will provide numerical information on the levels of caffeine in drinks. There are six columns, the first column contains the name of the drink, the second contains the category of drink (i.e bottled tea, teabags, instant coffee powder), the third contains the serving size, and the next two contain the amount of caffeine, and caffeine/100ml. I'd like to include a database that allows users to be able to search for drinks, filter by drink category and sort the numerical columns by ascending and descending totals. I'd also like users to be able to input data into the database.

I've managed to created the basic "skeleton" of the app with a home page and some tabs, I just need to add the database. The data is currently in an excel spreadsheet. I'm struggling to find a tutorial that shows how to include a database in an android app, and include the options to search and sort data. Can anyone please point me in the direction of a good tutorial, or advise me on how I add the database? Thanks

Comment: You can use the [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/) which has a good free  plan and Android studio intergation

Comment: If you want to store the data locally, then consider using Room database. Here is an official tutorial from the Android developers site that also contains samples: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to save your data, locally or remotely from API. If local is your desired one, you can check out [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). It uses Room, one of the Android Jetpack libraries, using SQL like schema and queries.